# Wie sagt man "to ring a bell"?

Tags: phrase

> Ich wohne in Bamberg. Kennst du Bamberg? - Ja, dieser Ort sagt mir was.

Ich weiß nicht, ob der Ausdruck *etwas sagt jemandem etwas* das passende Wort in diesem Kontext ist. Andere Vorschläge wären schön.

Comment: _[Habe ich] schonmal gehört._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Einmal kann man den Ortsnamen kennen, wissen, wo Bamberg liegt und evtl. noch 2–3 Fakten nennen, die in Wikipedia stehen könnten. Dafür wird man aber oft einen anderen Ausdruck wählen, als wenn man Bamberg aus eigener Anschauung kennt, weil man da schon war und nicht bloß durchgefahren ist.

> Ich wohne in Bamberg. Kennst du Bamberg? – Ja, dieser Ort sagt mir was.

Das könnte man sagen, aber es klingt seltsam. Eine einfache, gängige Erwiderung wäre:

> Ich wohne in Bamberg. Kennst du Bamberg? – Ja, kenne ich.

Es könnte sein, dass man Bamberg nur aus Büchern kennt, z. B. man hat eine Bildungsreise dorthin intensiv vorbereitet, war dann jedoch verhindert. Man würde dann wohl die Zustimmung einschränken:

> Ich wohne in Bamberg. Kennst du Bamberg? – Ja, aber nur aus Büchern.

Umgekehrt kann man auch die Verneinung einschränken:

> Ich wohne in Bamberg. Kennst du Bamberg? – Nein, ich weiß, wo es liegt, und das war es schon.
>
> Das bringt in mir was zum Klingen.

Wäre eine Formulierung, die an die ringing Bell erinnert, aber wäre für so einen Fall ungewöhnlich. Man verwendet es, wenn die Erinnerung unscharf ist, und durch Anregung wieder reanimiert werden kann. Hier steht aber nicht ein Panorama oder eine Gasse vor Augen, sondern nur das Wort. Das fällt aber im Deutschen so oft, dass es kaum aus den Tiefen des Gedächtnisses kommen kann. Vom Ausland aus betrachtet, oder bei deutlich kleineren Orten ist aber auch das möglich.

Konkrete Antworten scheinen mir jeweils besser:

- Ich komme selbst aus Bamberg und war dort 12 Jahre Bürgermeister!
- Da war ich schon in Urlaub.
- Nur vom Durchfahren.
- Nach Bayern bringen mich keine 10 Pferde!

Answer (score 7):

Ja! Man sagt durchaus

> Der Name sagt mir was!

Wahlweise könnte man noch sagen:

> - Bamberg? Ja, es dämmert [bei mir]. *(wenn die Erinnerung doch etwas vage ist)*
> - Ja, den Namen habe ich noch auf dem Schirm / auf dem Kasten. *(umgangssprachlich)*
> - Der Name ist mir nicht fremd / unbekannt.
> - Ja, es ist mir ein Begriff.

Answer (score 5):

Wörtlich könnte man auch sagen *da klingelt was (bei mir)*.